# Summernote non-bootstrap version problems with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

I found out some strange error on my project so as on summernote website [example](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#without-bootstrap):

```css
#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

#summernote {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="summernote"></div>
  <script>
      $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Write your blog content here...',
        tabsize: 1,
        height: 100,
        focus: true
      });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try opening this example in full window and resize editor more than full window height. Try scrolling down and you will get some bug where it moves back up after you scroll over tab with buttons.

Also on my project it did that but I added additional div and now when I scroll over tab with buttons I editor hide everything besides his border - here is an screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just set **followingToolbar: false,** in summernote options :

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
    placeholder: 'Write your blog content here...',
    tabsize: 1,
    height: 100,
    focus: true,
    followingToolbar: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your question presented by gif image is :
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/3126#issue-399125267

and answer is :

Just change in summernote-lite.js -
From this:-

```
if ((currentOffset > activateOffset) && (currentOffset < deactivateOffsetBottom)) {
this.$toolbar.css({
position: 'fixed',
top: otherBarHeight,
width: editorWidth
});
}
```

To this:-

```
if ((currentOffset > activateOffset) && (currentOffset < deactivateOffsetBottom)) {
this.$toolbar.css({
position: 'relative',
top: otherBarHeight,
width: editorWidth
});
}
```

this change works for me...
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/3126#issuecomment-466647611